# Fechas largas rompen la alineación del listado de preguntas para una medalla

Tags: bug, medallas, diseño

En medallas obtenidas por preguntas o respuestas se ve que, en el listado de preguntas, una fecha larga puede romper el estilo. Por ejemplo en:

> #### https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20?page=2
>
> [image: Se rompe el formato. El autor pasa a la izquierda, debajo del título de la pregunta, en vez de estar alineado a la derecha]

El ancho normal del div de la derecha es 200px:

> [image: Estilo correcto, con .single-badge-awarded con 200px de ancho]

Pero el texto que usamos en español para las fechas largas a veces se pasa de ese ancho, corriendo a todo el div hacia abajo:

> [image: Fecha larga que se pasa de los 200px de ancho]

No creo que sea un bug importante -es más, pensé que ya estaba reportado-, pero lo publico para dejar registro.

Comment: Obviamente otra solución sería acortar el texto, pero [no se puede](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43403918#43403918) modificar el formato de fecha desde Transifex.

Comment: podríamos cambiar `otorgada` por `dada` ¿?

Comment: @Rubén es cierto. Tanto `Dada` como `Ganada` resuelven el problema, pero como se utiliza "*otorgada*" en *todo* el sitio, no es algo que me anime a hacer, siendo que es un detalle de diseño nada más (se ve muy feo, pero no es grave).